# SFTP Repos & SftpException

Tags: java, apache, ant, ivy

[Using Apache Ivy]

I am trying to configure my settings file to use an SFTP repo (we have an FTP server at the office) and getting a NoClassDefFoundError for the com/jcraft.jsch.SftpException class.  Here is the definition in my file:

```
<sftp user="myuser" userPassword="mypasswd"> 
    <ivy pattern="ftp://MyFtpServer/some/path/artifacts/[organisation]/[module]-[revision]-ivy.xml"/> 
    <artifact pattern="ftp://MyFtpServer/some/path/artifacts/[organisation]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/> 
</sftp>
```

When I run the "resolve" target in my build (which runs configure, then resolve, then retrieve Ivy tasks), I get the following build error during the ivy:resolve phase:

**BUILD FAILED**

*C:\blah\workspace\MyProject\build.xml:53: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/SftpException 
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)*

Followed by a very, very lengthy stacktrace.

I am using the latest (2.2.0) version of Ivy - do I need to do something? Am I missing a JAR or other resource?

Thanks for any help or insight here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) lib in the ant/lib directory (or in your ant classpath). This lib is required by the sftp resolver.